# When to use uno, when to use un

Tags: word-usage, grammar, articles

I came across this sentence:

> *C'è uno zoo nella città*

Why can't I say

> *C'è un zoo nella città*?

I understand *uno* is a number and *un* is an indefinite article. So it seems to me *un* is more appropriate a use in this sentence. So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

These are the rules to follow:

L’articolo maschile singolare **[uno](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/articoli-indeterminativi_%28La_grammatica_italiana%29/)** si usa:

> – davanti a parole che cominciano con i o j con il valore di ➔semiconsonante, gn di gnomo, ps, pn, s seguita da consonante, sci-, sce-, x, y, z.

- uno iettatore, uno juventino, uno gnocco, uno psicologo, uno pneumotorace, uno storico, uno sciocco, uno xilofono, uno yen, uno zio.

> – davanti a parole che cominciano con una consonante seguita da un’altra consonante (diversa da l o r).

- uno pterodattilo, 
  uno ’ndranghetista, 
  *ma un flusso, un gradino.*

> -La forma con ➔troncamento un si usa in tutti gli altri casi:

- un amico,
  un dado,
  un terreno,
  un erede.